# Gaining application/module context from a symfony task

Tags: php, symfony1

I have written a reporting suite, and I have a specific report that builds a CSV file. Serving this file via a browser on demand isn't an issue, but I need to be able to build this CSV file nightly, and email round a link to be able to download it.

Essentially, I need to be able to replace a specific action with a symfony task, run via cron. So how do I gain application/module context from a symfony task? And secondly, how would I invoke the SwiftMailer library from a symfony task?

I'm using symfony v1.4.4 and PHP v.5.2.13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the configure() function of your task, you need to define the application involved in your task :

```
$this->addOptions(array(
  new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name','frontend'),
  new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'dev'),
  new sfCommandOption('connection', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The connection name', 'doctrine'),
));
```

And then you have to create the context in the execute() function :

```
sfContext::createInstance($this->configuration);
```

Finally you can call Swift very easily :

```
$this->getMailer()->composeAndSend($sender,$dest, $subject, $mailBody);
```

Comment: Great stuff, though I see symfony complaining about sending headers and what not; which obviously isn't needed on the CLI. Seems there wasn't 100% forethought for this when Fabien put the framework together.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we we have `--application` and `--env` CLI task options defined in `taskName::configure()` method

Then receiving application context in `taskName::execute()` method will look like:

```
$context = sfContext::createInstance(ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration($options['application'], $options['env']))
```

Comment: I get a 'PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class sfLogger in .../config_core_compile.yml.php' when trying that.